# WP_Query and a Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a wordpress function which loops using WP_Query, and everything works, but I am also getting a notice of an error and I would like to remove whatever this error is.  Here is my code...

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'media_streams', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        $can_view_content = wc_memberships_user_can( get_current_user_id(), 'view', array( 'post' => get_the_ID() ) );
        if ( $can_view_content ) :
        $count++;
        ?>

        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;"><?php the_post_thumbnail( array(300), array('style' => 'width:60px;') ); ?></th>
            <th><?php the_title(); ?></th>
            <th style="text-align:right; font-size:2em;"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        endif;
        endwhile;
        ?>
```

Any ideas as to what could be causing this notice?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's `posts_per_page' => -1`

*minus one* posts per page... (?)